# How can my website detect if a browser is using a dark/light theme NOT if the OS is using a theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have the favicon change based on a browsers theme. I have tried `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches` but this seems to only detect the computers color theme, not the browser. Is it possible to get just the browsers theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mistaken, `prefers-color-scheme` ALSO gets the preference of the browser's theme — but not in the way you think. If you're thinking about those browser themes you find on the Chrome Web Store or Firefox's Add-On Store, unfortunately, none of the current browsers implement in such that it accommodates for WebExtensions.

`prefers-color-scheme` gets the theme from the OS, but ALSO the browser if its overridden or behind a user preference. On Firefox, adding `ui.systemUsesDarkTheme` to `about:config` and setting it to `0` always makes `(prefers-color-scheme: dark)` true regardless of the OS's preference. On Android, the Samsung Browser I believe has a option in three dots menu to enable dark mode all the time, which also overrides Android's settings. **So, continue using `prefers-color-scheme` and expect future browsers to do what you're looking for.**

Comment: I am trying to detect the default themes available in Firefox and Chrome but they aren't being detected.

To test this in Firefox I have gone into the burger button -> customize -> theme -> dark/light.

When I change the theme here in the browser it continues to only change my websites favicon when I change the Windows 10 computer settings theme.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're aren't missing anything. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1529323 which shows it is currently being implemented in Firefox, but has not been released yet. Continue using `prefers-color-scheme` like-so and future browser updates will have that behavior.